# How to 'await' ads load call back?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, admob

I want to load the ad first and `showAd()` later. Although I use await on load, it still does not 'await' in `InterstitialAdLoadCallback()` since it is a callback.

```
InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
print("OUTPUT 1");
await InterstitialAd.load(
  adUnitId: '123456789',
  request: AdRequest(),
  adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      print("OUTPUT 2");
      _interstitialAd = ad;
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (err) {
      _interstitialAd = null;
    },
  ),
);
print("OUTPUT 3");
```

**Output:**

```
OUTPUT 1
OUTPUT 3
OUTPUT 2
```

How to 'await' in `InterstitialAdLoadCallback()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `await` an operation that does not directly expose a `Future`, you can use a [`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html) to create and manage one:

```dart
var adCompleter = Completer<void>();
InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
await InterstitialAd.load(
  adUnitId: '123456789',
  request: AdRequest(),
  adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
    onAdLoaded: (ad) {
      _interstitialAd = ad;
      adCompleter.complete();
    },
    onAdFailedToLoad: (err) {
      _interstitialAd = null;
      adCompleter.completeError(err);
    },
  ),
);
await adCompleter.future;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I've heard of `Completer`.